# Hidden RAW Disk Partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

While installing Windows 10 I formatted and created the new partition on **disk 1** and **disk 2** and I selected **disk 1** for the Windows 10 installation location.

But now, the second disk is set as RAW and does not appear under This PC in Explorer. Now I am planning to install Ubuntu on disk 2 but I am afraid to format it as the disk is being used for Windows.

I would like to know if it is safe to format it and install Ubuntu on it.

Here is the screenshot of Disk Management:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. "RAW" means it is unformatted or formatted with a filesystem that Windows does not recognized, so in Windows' sense it is synonymous to "unused". You should find the partition deletable if you right click on it in Disk Management, while Windows would not allow that if it is not "safe" (like for the two partitions other than `C:` on Disk 0).

It is even safe to nuke the partition table and the MBR of Disk 1 (e.g. `diskpart` -> `select disk 1` -> `clean`) so that you can totally "start from scratch" when you install Ubuntu.